# Take inputs and store in array

Tags: python, arrays, input

I just started Python and I'm writing a hangman project but I was just wondering about how to take N inputs and store them in an array where N is the number of letters in a string variable.

I tried to do something like that but I want the inputs to be stored in an array to use them later (that's not the real program obviously but just the main idea).

```
import random

words = ["banana", "orange", "cherry", "apple", "peach", "watermelon", "blueberry"]
word = random.choice(words)
for count in range(len(word)):
    guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add a value to a list? Have you seen https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists (`append`)?

Comment: Try `guesses = [input("Enter a guess: ") for _ in word]` -- I don't think that gets you what you need to implement hangman, but it'll do `N` input prompts and put them all in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Create guess list above your for loop
And inside for loop enter append function

```
guess = []
for i in range (n):
    guess.append(input("enter guess"))
```

You can also use shorthand as

```
guesses = [input("Enter a guess: ") for i in range(n)]
```

Use for loop as you want for range or for i in word

Hope this helps